# Trigger to increase rank of higher ranks in a column when found duplicate

Tags: sorting, triggers, insert, ranking

following setting:

- I have a table with 2 columns colA (datatype varchar) and colB
  (datatype int)
- colB is called "rank", which should be unique (i.e. 1,2,3), not necessarily ordered

Challenge:

if the user will insert a new row (or update an existing one) and assigns a new (not yet existing) rank (e.g. 4) => no problem.

But: if the user will insert a new row (or update an existing one) which already exists (e.g. 2) => in this case, the trigger should increase all ranks below (i.e. 2 and 3) by one. So, 2 becomes 3, and 3 becomes 4.

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
colA varchar(5), 
colB int
)

INSERT INTO Test 
VALUES 
('Row1', 1),
('Row2', 2),
('Row3', 3)
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO Test
Values
('Row4', 2)
```

should bring the following result:

```
Row1 => 1
Row2 => 3
Row3 => 4
Row4 => 2
```

Challenge 2: what to do if the ranks have gaps, i.e.

```
Row1 => 1
Row2 => 2
Row3 => 4
```

Now, when I want to insert a new row (e.g. Row4, 2) the table should look like this:

```
Row1 => 1
Row2 => 3
Row3 => 4
Row4 => 2
```

Any ideas? I dont even now how to deal with this...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found some...what do you say about this? Suggestions for improvement?

```
--Create Table Test
create table Test (colA varchar(5), colB int)

insert into test 
values 
('Row1', 1),
('Row2', 3),
('Row3', 2),
('Row4', 5),
('Row5', 4)

--Create Trigger
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_rank_insert]
ON [dbo].[Test] 
AFTER Insert
AS 

DECLARE 
    @newColA varchar(10), 
    @newColB int,
SET @newColA = (Select colA from inserted)
SET @newColB = (Select colB from inserted)

DECLARE @rankid int 
DECLARE rank_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT colB 
    FROM Test 
    ORDER by colB asc

OPEN rank_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM rank_cursor INTO @rankid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    IF (@rankid < @newColB)
        FETCH NEXT FROM rank_cursor INTO @rankid

    ELSE  
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE Test 
            SET ColB = ColB + 1
            WHERE ColA <> @newColA and ColB >= @newColB

        BREAK

     END 

    FETCH NEXT FROM rank_cursor INTO @rankid

END

CLOSE rank_cursor 
DEALLOCATE rank_cursor

--Test
INSERT INTO Test Values ('Row6', 2)
INSERT INTO Test Values ('Row7', 5)
```